# Facebook Dev: What is this?

Tags: facebook

Okay so for this page:

http://www.facebook.com/ESPN?sk=app_224097940938597

Which appears on the left hand bar between ESPN Fanwhich and ESPN Live Chat.

That isn't a canvas but it isn't a static page that I can gather. I found this tutorial: http://www.kimwoodbridge.com/how-to-add-a-custom-tab-to-a-facebook-fan-page/

But that is creating static content.

What I'm wondering is how I can create a dynamic page within a tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a "dynamic" page within a tab is pretty easy.  Install the [Developer's App](http://www.facebook.com/developers/) and create a new application.  There are tons of posts all over google about creating new Facebook apps, so you should be able to find those pretty easily.

After you create a new application, you set up the Tab information for it under "Facebook Integration."

The way tabs work is they create an iFrame in the Facebook canvas that loads a page from your webserver.  You can do whatever you want within that iframe to make a dynamic page.  Also, since it's an iframe, you can have links that go all over the place and build a whole mini-site which works inside the Facebook canvas.

Basically, you do the same thing you would normally do to create a dynamic page/site, and set up a Facebook application that points to it.  There are a few caveats to building Facebook applications, but they're hard to enumerate without specific scenarios.  The biggest one (and it's well documented) is that the size of a tab is 520px wide, so whatever you build has to fit within that width.  The length can be whatever you want, Facebook has APIs in place that let you automatically resize the iframe as needed.

Good luck, and welcome to Facebook programming.  Prepare to rip your hair out, because everything changes every 4-6 weeks :x